# How do I associate pressing a button in my interface to transferring to another view?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to make it so that when a UIButton in my toolbar that I set in my xib file is pressed, a new controller is loaded into view.

How do I implement that? I have tried duplicating the FlipViewController, but I don't think you can have more than one of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. iPad (don't use UINavigationController for the whole screen).

You can switch with a nice animation like this:
(works only in app-delegate unless you change the line commented with `// works only in app delegate`.

```
UIViewController *ctrl = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"someXIBStuff" bundle:nil];


    CAKeyframeAnimation *theAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];
    theAnimation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(1.12,1.12,1)],
                           [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(1,1,1)],
                           nil];
    theAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    theAnimation.duration = 0.3;
    theAnimation.repeatCount = 0;
    theAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;


    theAnimation.timingFunctions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn], 
                                    nil
                                    ];

    [self.window.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"transform"];  

    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.3;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
    transition.delegate = self;

    [self.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil]; 

    self.window.rootViewController = ctrl; // works only in app delegate
    [ctrl release];
```

1. iPhone:
   Use [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (if possible). If not, you might use the example above.